# Deploy Web application over Azure using VSTS (Visual studio Team Service)

Tags: azure, automation, azure-devops, devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I want to fully automate the deployment of a web application using VSTS. I have a sample azure application and I want to create a build definition on it that contains building the solution, running unit tests, and deploying it over azure on IIS as its build steps. I am new to VSTS, I am finding it hard to automate the deployment using VSTS. Seeking some help on how to create the above build definition. Any slightest guidance will be helpful.

Comment: Do you solve this issue with their ways?

Answer (score 2):

Madhur,

You will find step by step up to date examples on the Visual Studio website:

1. [Build and deploy your ASP.NET 4 code to an Azure web app](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/aspnet/aspnet4-to-azure)
2. [Deploy ASP.NET apps to Azure web apps](https://www.visualstudio.com/ru-ru/docs/release/examples/azure/azure-web-apps-from-build-and-release-hubs)

First create a build definition to test and package you web app.

Second get familiar with release definition to deploy it on Azure. Or if you just want to do it in one place you can have everything in your build definition, it's up to you.

Also when creating a build or release definition on VSTS, the templates offered are very useful, everything is done so you juste have to feel the gaps. I advise you to take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Ive written up a walkthrough of this process at [my blog site](https://russellyoung.net/2016/11/09/continuous-deployment-of-a-asp-net-core-app-to-azure-using-vsts/), its for an asp.net core app but the principal is the same for a normal .net framework one, in fact its even easier because you just choose the Visual Studio Build template when creating the build definition.  My walkthrough also takes you through how to deploy the Azure resources you need to host the website - its good practise to use infrastructure as code for these, and maintain that code in the same way you treat source code, with CI and CD processes.